# Text field value in DOM, but does not display

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, input, pug

So I'm using Angular, Jade and expressjs to build in app. In one of my modals, I want to show existing user data. While it is inserted in the DOM, it doesn't get displayed:

http://snappy-app.com/s/read.php?pass=18877ecce9fae11bb69fd4900e24a9e7

http://snappy-app.com/s/read.php?pass=bd7db19fce630d20e5be74c5a3e63b9e

```
input.form-control.dash(type="email", name="newuseremail", required=true, ng-model="email", value="#{user.email}")
```

I also tried:

```
input.form-control.dash(type="email", name="newuseremail", required=true, ng-model="email", value=user.email)
```

But it didn't work.

User is a local in the Express app:

```
res.locals.user = req.user;
```

I cannot figure out what's wrong. Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

It's because angular model `email` value is empty. You shall not assign value to textbox, instead you shall assign it to angularjs model something like this:

```
function myCtrl($scope, MySrvc){
    MySrvc.getData(function(data){
        $scope.email = data.email;
    });
}
```

Or if you want to do it just with jade, then remove `ng-model` from textbox, but i don't suggest you to do this))